# Filter range of cells before passing to function

Tags: excel

I have a custom VBA function that I'm passing a large-ish range of cells to (~600 cells in a single column).

Here's the formula:

```
=getRootWord($I620, OFFSET($H$8,0,0,(ROW()-ROW($H$8)),1))
```

(*Basically, it says, "For the given cell calling this formula, pass in a range covering every cell above it, starting at row 8" - Is there a better way to write that formula?*)

My problem is, the custom VBA function is running a tad slow, and really, 90% of the cells passed in I don't need, and have to ignore within the VBA function.

Any cell above this cell that has a formula, instead of text, I'm not interested in.

**How can I use Excel formulas to operate on that range** (`OFFSET($H$8,0,0,(ROW()-ROW($H$8)),1)`) **and exclude any of the cells within that range that have a formula?** Or alternatively exclude any cells that are non-text?

Every cell in that column is either a formula (the same formula shown), or else text - no blanks, numbers, dates, or etc...

Comment: Maybe look into [xlCellTypeConstants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells). It's a bit hard to tell without seeing the actual UDF.

Comment: Most VBA UDFs can be sped up significantly by improving the code: so post your VBA code.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams I thought StackOverflow didn't like generic "Improve my code!" questions?

Comment: Anyway, my problem was that I didn't understand OFFSET() made the formula volatile, forcing recalculations of hundreds of cells unnecessarily. Removing the use of OFFSET() dramatically sped things up, by about 90%.

Answer (score 1):

`Application.ThisCell` or `Application.Caller` will refer to the cell that the UDF resides in. You can get the current row from one of those.

`Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` will only consider values; not formulas or blanks. `Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)` further tightens this to values that are text. If there are unconnected 'regions' of text values you might have to work through the Areas of the range union.

To get a range of cells in column I starting at row 8 to the row with the formula try,

```
dim rng as range

with application.caller.parent
    set rng = intersect(.range(.cells(8, "I"), .cells(application.caller.row-1, "I"))).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
end with

debug.print rng.address(0,0)
```

Comment: You can't use `Specialcells` in a UDF, unfortunately.

Comment: oops! that's my bad.

Comment: @Rory, but would it be able to call another macro to do the work for it?

Comment: @JvdV - nope - calling another macro from the UDF does not remove the limitation.

Comment: Thanks, I already tried using SpecialCells(). I was more looking for an Excel Formula method, prior to handing things into VBA.

Comment: Anyway, my problem was that I didn't understand OFFSET() made the formula volatile, forcing recalculations of hundreds of cells unnecessarily. Removing the use of OFFSET() dramatically sped things up, by about 90%. But if anyone knows the answer to my original non-VBA question, I'd be delighted to know the answer!